# Paypal IPN verification returns Invalid each time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, paypal, paypal-ipn

Basically I'm getting an "Invalid" return when I try to verify a payment made using the IPN Listeners from Paypal and NodeJS, I'm sending back a urlencoded post back to paypal, for them to tell me whether it is valid or not, however it always returns Invalid.

I have a node app, and I'm using expressJS to manage all these server calls.

I already tried 2 different approaches:

```
app.post('/ipn', bodyParser.text({ type: 'urlencoded' }), function (req, res) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
    console.log('accedio al ipn');
    //console.log(req.body);
    var params = req.body;
    ipn.verify(string, {'allow_sandbox': true}, function callback(err, msg) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(string);
            console.error(err);
          } else {
            // Do stuff with original params here

            if (params.payment_status == 'Completed') {
              // Payment has been confirmed as completed
            }
          }
    });
});
```

and

```
app.post('/ipn', bodyParser.text({ type: 'urlencoded' }), function (req, res) {
    console.log('Received POST /');
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log('\n\n');

    // STEP 1: read POST data
    req.body = req.body || {};
    res.status(200).send('OK');
    res.end();

    // read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
    var postreq = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    for (var key in req.body) {
        if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var value = querystring.escape(req.body[key]);
            postreq = postreq + "&" + key + "=" + value;
        }
    }

    // Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
    console.log('Posting back to paypal');
    console.log(postreq);
    console.log('\n\n');
    var options = {
        url: 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Connection': 'close'
        },
        body: postreq,
        strictSSL: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        requestCert: true,
        agent: false
    };

    request(options, function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

            // inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
            console.log(body);
            if (body.substring(0, 8) === 'VERIFIED') {
                // The IPN is verified, process it
                console.log('Verified IPN!');
                console.log('\n\n');

                // assign posted variables to local variables
                var item_name = req.body['item_name'];
                var item_number = req.body['item_number'];
                var payment_status = req.body['payment_status'];
                var payment_amount = req.body['mc_gross'];
                var payment_currency = req.body['mc_currency'];
                var txn_id = req.body['txn_id'];
                var receiver_email = req.body['receiver_email'];
                var payer_email = req.body['payer_email'];

                //Lets check a variable
                console.log("Checking variable");
                console.log("payment_status:", payment_status)
                console.log('\n\n');

                // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
                // To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
                console.log('Printing all key-value pairs...')
                for (var key in req.body) {
                    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        var value = req.body[key];
                        console.log(key + "=" + value);
                    }
                }

            } else if (body.substring(0, 7) === 'INVALID') {
                // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
                console.log('Invalid IPN!');
                console.log('\n\n');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Both of them return Invalid.

First example is taken from:
https://github.com/andzdroid/paypal-ipn

Second one is taken from:
https://github.com/HenryGau/node-paypal-ipn

As far as I know, I receive a payment notification using IPN on my server, then I resend that request to Paypal so I can verify it it's valid or not, for security purposes, this is all done within the sandbox environment. 
I also tried to send the request I get, but this time using POSTMAN, and it also returns Invalid, been stuck here for a while.

Note: I'm trying to use this for suscription payments, I don't know if this is relevant or not, just in case.